# Twilio chat member online status is always null

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

In my chat application I want to know if a channel member is online, but `'userInfoUpdated'` never fires when a new member comes and `member.userInfo.online` is always null whenever I want to get it. What am I doing wrong?

UPD:
Here the code is paused on member "updated" even, the member's `userInfo.online` field is still `null`
[image]

UPD2:
Now I've found this line from the documentaion

> Extended user information Note that UserInfo#online and UserInfo#notifiable properties are eligible to use only if reachability function enabled. You may check if it is enabled by reading value of Client~reachabilityEnabled [docs](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/0.11.1/docs/UserInfo.html)

Finally setting `reachabilityEnabled` on the backend solved my problem

Comment: Can you share the code you're using? When are you calling `member.userInfo.online`? When do you start listening for `userInfoUpdated`?

Comment: I have `member.on('userInfoUpdated')` inside `client.getChannelByUniqueName(uniqueName).then(channel=>{
channel.getMembers().forEach(member=>{
member.on('userInfoUpdated', ()=>{
//nothing happening
})
})
})`

Comment: Please share actual code rather than an image - as images aren't searchable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setting reachabilityEnabled on the backend solved my problem

Comment: I have been reading the documentation by twillio , your answere is right but at backend i am unable to set the property as it is not provided in UpdateServiceOptions. I have ReachabilityWebhooksEnabled , but this also does not work

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

From your comment you say that your code is:

```
client.getChannelByUniqueName(uniqueName).then(channel => {
  channel.getMembers().forEach(member => {
    member.on('userInfoUpdated', ()=>{ //nothing happening })
  })
})
```

I think I see the issue. [`channel.getMembers()` returns a Promise](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/0.11.1/docs/Channel.html#getMembers__anchor) that will asynchronously resolve with an array of `Member` objects. You're just calling `forEach` on the Promise itself. Try something like:

```
client.getChannelByUniqueName(uniqueName).then(channel => {
  return channel.getMembers()
}).then(members => {
  members.forEach(member => {
    member.on('userInfoUpdated', ()=>{ // something happening? })
  })
})
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: You're right, I've mistaken with the example, but still it work's the same way, I mean it doesn't work. Even when a user from the list joins channel `'userInfoUpdated'` doesn't fire and inspecting users list in debugger, the user online field is null

Comment: User "updated" event fires, but even inside this event handler the user's online field is still `null`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, members will be null if you didn't synchronized chat client at client startup.

So you need to override this callback and make sure that client synchronization is completed before using chat client methods -like getChannels or getMessages-.

```
override fun onClientSynchronization(status: ChatClient.SynchronizationStatus?) {
        if (status == ChatClient.SynchronizationStatus.COMPLETED) {
            // You can use chat client now
        }
    }
```

> You will receive an event to the client's listener or delegate via the synchronizationStatusUpdated method with a value of StatusCompleted. This is your indication the client is ready for business, and all User Channels have been obtained and subscribed to.

For more details please check this: [Initializing SDK Clients](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/initializing-sdk-clients#mobile-sdks)